# ControllerLinkBuilder/UriComponentsBuilder does not handle header forwarded properties

Tags: spring, https, http-headers, spring-hateoas

I added the following properties in my application.properties for a Spring boot application to be able to enable https:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true

server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.* //for testing purposes
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-companyname-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-companyname-forwarded-proto
server.tomcat.port-header=x-companyname-forwarded-port
```

It worked like it's supposed to work but whenever links are built from the ControllerLinkBuilder/UriComponentsBuilder it returns 'http'-links again.

It seems like the ControllerLinkBuilder doesn't take account of those properties.

Is it possible to make this work?

EDIT:

Spring version: 4.3.23.RELEASE
Spring Hateoas version: 0.24.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

For those having this issue with Spring > 5.1: It handles the forward-headers properly, but you have to enable it by setting the property `server.use-forward-headers=true`